# How to understand "every set in the model M of ZF"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In L.J.Halbeisen’s Combinatorial Set Theory (page 50), He wrote

> Assume ZF is consistent... there must be a model M of ZF. The model M can be easily described as a hierarchy of sets.
> For this we construct within the model M a certain hierarchy of sets
> and show that every set in M belongs to this hierarchy.

- I am confused about “every set in M”. Can I understand “every set in M” as “every element in M-universe(a class of sets) + functions(sets) + constant(empty set)”? (Here I think my question is somehow related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802655/is-it-circular-to-define-the-von-neumann-universe-using-sets)... We know something about sets first and put them in M? Or we have filtered some "rough sets" don't satisfy ZF and put them in M? )  In particular, In [image: Proof of Theorem3.12], is the reason that *w*$\in$M simply *w* is a set? If it is the reason, should I use the axiom schema of separation to say *w* is a set?
- As for “construct within the model M a certain hierarchy of sets”, can I understand “within the model M” as the construction of cumulative hierarchy V follows ZF and other theorems such as transfinite recursion theorem which M models?

Comment: See also Lorenz Halbeisen & Regula Krapf, Gödel's Theorems and Zermelo's Axioms (Birkhauser, 2020), **Ch.14 Models of Set Theory**: Let us assume that $\mathsf {ZF}$ is consistent. Then, by Godel's Completeness Theorem, we know that there is a model $M$ of $\mathsf {ZF}$. Within $M$, by induction on $\alpha \in \Omega$  we define the sets $V_{\alpha}$ [the cumulative hierarchy]. By construction, for each$\alpha \in \Omega$, $V_{\alpha}$ is a set in the model $M$. We can prove that the class $V$, called the *cumulative hierarchy*, is equal to $M$ (i.e.,$V$ contains all sets of $M$).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA : I don’t have enough background knowledge of model theory. It seems to me model/structure and formal languages are in two dimensions, such as I know what successor is in natural numbers then can use this knowledge to state the description of successor in the corresponding language is true . So I am not sure is this the same as the relationship of sets in model M and sets ZF describe. Can I take V as sets ZF describe and construction of V follows ZF, such as Halbeisen added in Combinatorial Set Theory, V$_\alpha$ is(to me: “can be”) a set by Axiom Schema of Replacement?

Comment: As for sets in M, we “deleted” some “sets” (such as class) because it is a model of ZF, just like we have to “deleted” some other numbers from $\mathbb{Z}$ to get $\mathbb{N}$ resulted in the different description about 0? And in my question about why *w*$\in$ M is that because *w* is a set by some intuitive ideas of the general set we have already known and it indeed satisfies ZF(axiom Schema of separation)?

Comment: "Obviously" the model $M$ is described in the meta-theory that is a mathematical theory using set language. In the meta- the author defines the hierarchy $V$ that "lives" in $M$ and in the meta- the author proves that $V$ contains every element of $M$ (of course, the details must be studied on a textbook).